# Windows Web server 2008 boot take long time

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, boot

I have a server using windwos web server 2008 R2 ( 64bit)
Yesterday I saw it was very slowly and dont response to request correctly then try to restart it,
windows try to booting and show start screen on windows, for a long time ( 4 hours )
it show the start screen but it response to keyboard and mouse ( doesn't hang up ) and windows and it's service dosne't start.
I restart again and use safe mode , it stop on CLASSPNP.sys 
I ask my datacenter to installing a new windows but they told this will erase all data on server.
Is there any way to fix this problem?
Thanks

I have 2 hard drive which setup as a RAID1 by windows, Can I install a fresh windows on one this hard drive and sure that another hard drive and it's data is safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will erase all data on the server, but there are backups to restore from when it's done, right?

Comment: correct, new windows install will erase all data on the C drive(or the OS drive). I suggest taking an image of the disk or make a copy of all data on the machine, before you let them try things.

Comment: erase data from C drive or all drives? my main data store on D drive